# Data entered into cell replicates in all sheets unneccesarily?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

Example: I enter data into sheet 29 cell 7, then cell 7 from 1-31 shows the same data.

How do I undo this? It was not a problem yesterday. There is no formula in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you have multiple sheets selected simultaneously. 
Try clicking on a single sheet tab.

Comment: No that's not it, sorry.